# Occurence of more than one fields grouped by label

Tags: python, pandas, count

I apologize if this is a possible duplicate. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
label          api_spec_id             content                              
             375.0  
             375.0  
             375.0        Request Parameter Removed, Field type missing, Violation
             375.0        Path Removed w/o Deprecation
             385.0  
minor        385.0        Request Type Change,Removed param, Interface missing
patch        395.0        Path Removed w/o Deprecation
patch        395.0        Path Removed w/o Deprecation
minor        400.0        New Required Request Property
minor        400.0        Response Success State Removed, Violation
major        400.0        Field type changed
```

I want to calculate the `unique` number of `api_spec_id`, where in `content`, they have more than one fields( they are always comma separated),for every label category.

So, the expected output would be:

`patch`: 0

`minor`:  2

`major` : 0

`Nan`: 1

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: patch can be 0, all of its lines without a comma?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, it was a mistake on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) on the boolean Series obtained from [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to identify strings containing a comma:

```
out = (df[df['content'].str.contains(',').fillna(False)]
       .groupby('label', dropna=False)['api_spec_id'].nunique()
       .reindex(df['label'].unique(), fill_value=0)
      )
```

Or

```
out = (
 df['api_spec_id'].where(df['content'].str.contains(',').fillna(False))
 .groupby(df['label'], dropna=False).nunique()
)
```

Output:

```
label
NaN      1
minor    2
patch    0
major    0
Name: api_spec_id, dtype: int64
```